# Trying to get an ubuntu headless server to call home

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, pptp

I would like to install PPTP on my remote ubuntu server, so that it will connect back to the main office, so that backups, and and also data transfer can take place.

Can anyone suggest a good guide for getting an ubuntu headless server, (or any linux for that matter) dialing PPTP on bootup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not PPTP related: If you can use OpenVPN, it's support on Ubuntu is excellent. Just edit /etc/default/openvpn to default some OpenVPN tunnels to auto-start on boot. On the client configuration, use some passphrase-less certificate and keys, so OpenVPN does not stop asking for a passphrase.

Alternatively, on the PPTP side of things, investigate using /etc/network/interfaces, to define

```
 auto callhome
 iface callhome inet ppp
 provider callhomeprovider
```

This creates a "callhome" pseudo interface, that is auto-brought-up on boot, that in turn calls ppp's /etc/ppp/peers/callhomeprovider config-file. This does not require any graphical clients. For configuring that, check out the standard PPTP-client's docs.

Comment: I will try this and get back to you as soon as I can, thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

How about trying this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VPNClient#Manually%20configuring%20your%20connection

Answer (score 0):

On the page here: http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/howto-ubuntu.phtml there's a section labeled "Configuration, by hand."  This includes CLI directions for the PPTP client.

Answer (score -1):

Install Ubuntu Server and the pptpd package which is a pptp server listening for connections. Then you can use windows vpn client and the linux pppoeconf or kppp to connect to your server. You can use this guide: http://poptop.sourceforge.net/dox/debian-howto.phtml , which is a guide for Debian, but works on Ubuntu.

Comment: OP is asking for client, now server :)

Answer (score -1):

For a headless/non-gui setup install and configure wvdial to call home and add wvdial to the bottom of /etc/rc.local as a background process to have it start on bootup.

Comment: looking into wvdial - it seems that this is used to dial the modem? The system is already has Internet connectivity, and just needs to connect to our vpn server.